# Create 2 separate collection records in one post request

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm working on a project for a local football club and have started working on the admin panel side. My desired effect is to allow someone to visit `/register-team` where they are presented a form, input their data, and in a single POST request create A. the admin user account in the `users` collection and B. create the team in the `teams` collection.

Current Code

```
module.exports.postRegisterTeam = async (req, res) => {
    const { teamName, firstName, lastName, email, password, role } = req.body;

    try {
        const admin = await User.create({ firstName, lastName, email, password, role });
        const team = await Team.create({ teamName });
        console.log('Admin user created: ' + admin);
        console.log('Team created: ' + team);
    } catch (err) {
        const errors = handleErrors(err);
        res.status(400).json({ errors });
    }
};
```

Currently, it is "working" because the user is created if all fields are valid, and then it creates the team if the team name exists on my form. `handleErrors` is working based off of MongoDB errors instead of client-side so I have omitted that from this post, but is there a way to validate both User and Team and only create the records when all fields are valid in one POST request or do I just need to modify my schema for Users to include the Team value and not use a separate Team schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `.create` returns a promise. You may chain the creation like:

```
await User.create({ firstName, lastName, email, password, role })
  .then((admin) => {
    console.log('Admin user created: ' + admin);
    const team = await Team.create({ teamName })
      .then((team) => console.log('Team created: ', team))
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error occurred while team creation ' + err);
        //here you may remove the previously created User if error occurs
      });
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log('Error occurred while creating User'))
```